# Prove that $g^{-1}\langle X\rangle g = \langle g^{-1}Xg\rangle$

Tags: group-theory

Prove that $g^{-1}\langle X\rangle g = \langle g^{-1}Xg \rangle$.

I can see it is clear, but I don't know how to give explanation / written proof.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Hint 1

You need only to prove the inclusion
$$
\langle g^{-1} X g \rangle \le g^{-1} \langle X \rangle g,
$$
and then apply it with $X$ replaced by $g^{-1} X g$ and $ g$ replaced by $g^{-1}$.

Hint 2

It is enough to show that $g^{-1} X g \subseteq g^{-1} \langle X \rangle g$